# Request for Official Clarification on Proper Location of Meta Questions for SE 2.0 Sites

Tags: support, meta, scope, stackexchange-2.0

On meta.webapps, Robert Cartaino ♦ says

> This meta site (meta.webapps) is for
>   question about the operation and
>   administration of this site
>   (webapps.stackexchange.com)
>   specifically. Any questions about the
>   Network or the engine should be
>   redirected to
>   http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

[(source)](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/is-this-meta-site-going-to-get-merged-with-meta-stackoverflow-com-at-some-point/13#13)

Yet Jeff Atwood ♦ says here at MSO that [a question about rendering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55512/rendering-glitch-in-the-webapps-faq-closed) belongs instead on meta.webapps, even though it concerns the SE 2.0 engine and not the "operation and administration of [webapps]".

Which ♦ is right, or do they belong on MSE?

Comment: This can only be settled in a steel cage.

Comment: Thank you for asking this, I was wondering this myself. I had assumed that quesitons about the engine would go here, but Jeff closed that rendering question...

Comment: Off to the thunderdome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're in a bit of an anomalous state at the moment. Web Apps is the first site launched as a beta site from Area 51. And the process for launching a beta site is, itself, *also* in beta.

So questions like "the faq is wrong ... the close reasons are mislabeled ... etc" are *technically* about the Network but, as far as everyone on that site is concerned, they are really more along the lines of "hey, problem with *our* site."

I'm okay with that. In the future, when we have the process flushed out, these first-time problems won't happen and it will be much clearer as to what belongs on meta.whatever (site-specific questions) and what belongs on meta.stackoverflow (network discussions and feature requests).

Comment: So the existing Stack Overflow Trilogy + API/Apps are not considered part of the Network? Or are they part of the Network but continue to run separate code-bases?

Comment: The point was that Web Apps is the first site launched from Area 51 and the beta process itself is also being tested. I updated my post.

Comment: So sad I was left out only because I did not commit :(

Answer (score 2):

If Cartaino is right, here's a list of questions on meta.webapps that should be closed or migrated:

[Rendering glitch in the WebApps FAQ.](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/rendering-glitch-in-the-webapps-faq)
[Activity bugs for "seen" and "visited" in profile](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/activity-bugs-for-seen-and-visited-in-profile)
[Badge total not updating](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/badge-total-not-updating)
[No rep for question upvotes?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/no-rep-for-question-upvotes)
https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/why-is-the-questions-page-empty

Comment: I only asked my question on meta.webapps because Jeff closed that rendering question here. I'd be in favor of migrating them all over here.

Comment: actually many of these are specific to the code paths around se 2.0 sites and per-child metas, so.. with all respect, you're wrong. They need to stay on the respective sites they relate to.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a mistake to insist that questions about the network or the engine belong on meta.stackoverflow.com  MSO is already dominated by people from SO and has its own community, and there's only minimal interaction by people from SF (for example).  I'd expect the experts from other areas to be even more mystified by MSO.  So it's going to be off-putting to them to have to deal with MSO whenever they do have a meta question.

Although Joel has stopped comparing SE 2.0 to Usenet, it might be time to bite the bullet and put together a real FAQ for the basics of all the sites.