# Migrate questions from meta stackexchange sites to meta.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, stackexchange-2.0, meta

Several of the questions on the meta site of WebApps are about the stackexchange engine itself. There should be a way to migrate those questions to a different meta site. I believe Robert [said](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/is-this-meta-site-going-to-get-merged-with-meta-stackoverflow-com-at-some-point/13#13) that those questions should be on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Otherwise that meta site will become a mess, similar to how this meta site is about many different topics.

Comment: Related clarification: [Request for Official Clarification on Proper Location of Meta Questions for SE 2.0 Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55513/request-for-official-clarification-on-proper-location-of-meta-questions-for-se-2). You might consider citing Robert's words from the Beta site in your question body, since there's only 489 of you who can even see that site.

Comment: Everything posted here also applies for meta.stackexchange.com, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now sorted in that moderators can migrate **to** any site in the network - even the Meta Stack Overflow **from** any site (that they're a moderator of).

So if you're a mod - migrate away.

If you're not a mod, flag the question and see it migrate (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

A certain amount of duplication between sites is fine -- in my estimation about 10 to 15 percent.

I know [some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker) members of our community go absolutely bonkers if they see *any* duplication of *any* content of any kind, but... I don't agree with these folks. :)

So, it is OK **as long as it's not overwhelming the topic-specific ("child") metas**, and right now it's a tiny fraction of the questions on those topic-specific metas. So not worth worrying about at the moment.

Also, bear in mind that not all sites will *survive* beta, so they don't get network privileges -- including question migration rights -- until they've proven they can survive.

edit:

**In general metas are black (grey?) holes -- once something gets migrated to meta, that's it, it can't be migrated anywhere else.** This is 100% intentional, and all metas will behave this way.

(yes, you could make a case that we should support migrate-to-meta-so since that's the "national capital", perhaps.. but it feels risky to me.)

Comment: I suppose I was really asking for the migration reason to be there when the site leaves beta - but I couldn't see the harm in having a migrate to meta for bugs now.

Comment: when there are over a dozen SE sites, is the team really going to be combing all the meta SE sites for bug reports? seems like it'll be easier for you guys if the meta SE sites can migrate the question here if it is a bug/feature-request pertaining to the core site software

Comment: @kip some of the engine features are in fact exclusive to SE 2.0 sites. For example, "child meta" and all child meta behavior. Eventually, once we have MILLIONS of sites, yes, but in the near future this is fine.

Comment: We finally have a system on the internet that is better than Forums. Forums languish because the same content gets posted over and over.  I'm ok with a little duplication -- especially now that the answers be merged and a stub left for searching. I think that's the second-best thing since sliced bread; but I'm not ok with that stuff staying open because we've criminalized the process of closing duplicate/off-topic/Subjective and Argumentative questions. And by we, I mean those that don't stand up for the closers.

Comment: @Kip: Seems like this would be one of the functions of the moderators of each site. If they discover an engine problem on their site, they can post on MSO.

Comment: @Jeff, So now we've got graduated sites with the same question on multiple SE2.0 sites.  Moderators can't be combing other metas looking to see if there's a [status-completed] on a specific issue.

Comment: "yes, you could make a case that we should support migrate-to-meta-so since that's the "national capital", perhaps.." -- isn't that the whole point here?

Comment: Cross-posting can be viewed as a form of inclusive migration. The purpose of such capability is not to eliminate duplication but to allow ALL presumed-relevant sets of eyes to see any given question.  For the non-site-specific meta.SO general questions, shouldn't these be visible and answerable in (i.e., crossposted to) all the meta sites, at least on an opt-in basis for those users who want to see that content on the local metas?

Comment: @t.. you can already use Stack Exchange tag sets to do that, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/

Comment: @Jeff, tagsets (great feature, thanks!) provide inward "pull" cross-reading, but not full outward "push" cross-posting. Both can be unified if "site" is explicitly treated as a (not necessarily displayed) tag, such as [site:Stackoverflow] or [site:CS-theory], with [originating-site:X] as a possible further indication of the point of origin. Adding these designations to the postings would be cross-posting and placing them, or wildcards including them, in the tagset, would provide cross-reading in perhaps a cleaner way than the global checklist of which sites are in/out of the tagset rubric.