# Posting a question from another Meta - is this pseudo-migration acceptable?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette, stackexchange-2.0

Did you ever realize that you can't flag an answer that you've accepted? If not, don't worry, neither did SO and Meta veteran (Metaran?) [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303?tab=accounts#tab-top), who positted a question about a missing flag link on the Gaming Meta last week. It's such a subtle point that can easily be missed. And a point that is not clearly established anywhere on this Meta!

I could go on, but then I would be invalidating the point of my question here - is it okay to repost this stuff onto this parent Meta? As Jeff states in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55778/migrate-questions-from-meta-stackexchange-sites-to-meta-stackoverflow-com/56656#56656), it's both fine to leave a number of core system questions on the SE2.0 Metas, and the status as a Beta is reason enough not to support migration.

Which I'm personally fine with, but in this scenario for example, it's information that's not pressing (so it's not about getting it into the eyes of the Team), but is still useful to actually have on this Meta. I could wait until the Beta ends, see if the site survives, and then wait for migration to be supported. That can be a long wait, and while there is no reason to rush, I find equally no reason to wait. So I've been weighing the idea of transcribing the question over to this Meta, and I thought I'd ask what people thought of this.

My specific example might be better as something included in a general flagging FAQ (which we are mysteriously lacking in, as our flagging stuff is divided in no less than three questions), but there are scenarios where someone in a Stack Exchange 2.0 Metas might stumble across some rather interesting information about the core system, which would be beneficial to have on the Meta. Is it then appropriate, in scenarios like this, to post the data from the other Meta over onto this Meta? What are your thoughts?

Comment: It's ok by me.  Go Wild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, core engine issues should be addressed here - there's nothing wrong with what you suggest!

As for the flagging issue, [we're pushing a fix out tonight](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278/missing-flag-link/676#676).

Comment: Ironically, by making that fix, it invalidates the need to make a new question on Meta because there's no longer a discrepancy to point out. Nevertheless, thank you much for both responses! ♪