# The great meta migration shuffle

Tags: discussion, migration, stack-exchange, meta

Questions tagged [superuser] or [serverfault] on meta.stackoverflow were recently migrated to their respective metas.  Will moderators have the ability to migrate future questions tagged [superuser] or [serverfault] on meta.stackoverflow over to those meta sites?

Comment: I asked on the blog announcement but got no reponse yet.

Answer (score 1):

see:
[Migrate questions from meta stackexchange sites to meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55778/migrate-questions-from-meta-stackexchange-sites-to-meta-stackoverflow-com/56656#56656)

Any confusion over "oops I asked on meta.so about su/sf" should be temporary and hardly worthy of a permanent close reason.

Comment: Yes, because people got used about the fact that computer questions shouldn't be asked on SO, and same for sysadmin questions ad SF, after a year :-]