# Provide a migrate to meta.stackoverflow.com on site specific metas

Tags: feature-request, migration, meta, stackexchange-2.0, per-site-meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrate questions from meta stackexchange sites to meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55778/migrate-questions-from-meta-stackexchange-sites-to-meta-stackoverflow-com)

Can we have a migrate to meta.stackoverflow.com close option on the child meta sites (meta.serverfault.com for example) so we can migrate [questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/472/se-2-0-meta-doesnt-award-rep-but-it-refers-to-rep) about the stackexchange engine to the right place instead of having people have to re-post in the right spot.

Comment: Are you getting these?