# Add a migration path from per-site meta sites to MSO to avoid dupes across sites

Tags: feature-request, migration, per-site-meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrate questions from meta stackexchange sites to meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55778/migrate-questions-from-meta-stackexchange-sites-to-meta-stackoverflow-com)

One issue that has come up with the new SE2.0 sites is where to post bug reports.  We are seeing bug reports being posted both on Meta and per-site metas.  Mods on these SE2.0 sites can generally work out whether it is something specific to the site or something general that belongs here.  However, if it is something that belongs here, there is no migration path available.  A mod (or a user) can repost the bug report here, but then you end up with a dead question on the per-site meta that is dependent on a post on another site.

Some bug reports belong here as they affect the entire network or are related to the SE engine, not a specific site.  Being able to migrate questions from the per-site meta here would help with tracking the issue and being able to mark it [status-complete] (hopefully!)

Example bug report on WebApps meta:  [Syntax highlighting is not working](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/689/syntax-highlighting-is-not-working)

---

Edit:  The current [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55778/migrate-questions-from-meta-stackexchange-sites-to-meta-stackoverflow-com/56656#56656) feels [status-completed] (though it isn't tagged as such) with an answer from Jeff to repost the question on Meta.  However, I don't feel that this is a great solution.  As stated, it means that the status of a post depends on a post on another site and keeping it updated is a mess.

Here's an example of a post or WebApps meta where the status is unknown with a comment saying there's a dupe here on Meta.  [Chrome 6.0.477.0: Blockquote error causes text duplication](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/461/chrome-6-0-477-0-blockquote-error-causes-text-duplication#comment-617)

Comment: It's a dupe - sorry ):

Comment: @ChrisF, Edited a bit.  The other seems [status-completed] with the answer to repost it here.  I'd like to go one step farther.