# Migration path from all metas to MSO

Tags: feature-request, migration, per-site-meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a migration path from per-site meta sites to MSO to avoid dupes across sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67637/add-a-migration-path-from-per-site-meta-sites-to-mso-to-avoid-dupes-across-sites)

A migration path should be added from *all* metas to MSO so that engine related meta posts can be moved where they belong -- here.

Examples: [1](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/show-only-web-application-chat-rooms-in-the-sidebar) [2](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/is-it-possible-to-add-a-bounty-to-someone-elses-question) [3](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/awarding-a-bounty-to-myself) [4](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194/are-we-going-to-get-the-beta-badge-for-participating-in-the-private-beta-of-gami) [5](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/are-we-going-to-have-more-legitimate-moderator-nominations-votes-now-that-were-o) [6](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/968/issue-with-assigning-a-bounty) ...

Sure, some posts may need massaging before they can be made general enough for MSO to consume; that can be easily done before the migration takes place.