# Can we link meta.stackoverflow from meta.X.SX?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes it's appropriate on a meta.X.SX site to say "This should be on meta.SO instead".  So there's a sort of hierarchy: parent -> meta -> meta.SO.  Would it make sense to have a link to 'meta.SO' on a meta site's banner (next to 'parent', perhaps)?

(I know that the link "feedback always welcome" points here, but that's not an obvious link to click on for people wanting support or to find out more about the SE network.)

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before.

Comment: @ChrisF: If it's a duplicate, please track down the original and close-as-duplicate!  Then I'll have an easy link to follow to vote for the original proposal.  However, I couldn't find it and I didn't get anything useful in the "related questions" list presented to me.

Comment: @Andrew - I will do when I have more than 5 minutes to search the site - of course I could be wrong, but by adding the comment I've alerted others who may have more time/better search skills.

Comment: @ChrisF: You mean http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55778/migrate-questions-from-meta-stackexchange-sites-to-meta-stackoverflow-com?

Comment: @Kenny - Possibly, but this question's not about migration per se.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes, but IIRC there were no question about "linking to meta.SO". Migration is the closest.

Comment: To clarify: this is definitely not about migration, just about a reasonably prominent link.