# Create a link between Meta from all the per site child meta sites

Tags: feature-request, meta, per-site-meta

Often I have a question, in a specific area (say Math SE or English SE) that is appropriate for the child meta of that site.

Then I realize it is not particular to the meta for that site but for Meta for all sites (like this question itself; I wanted a link to Meta Stack Exchange from meta.english, but realized no meta sites had such a link).

Wouldn't it be nice to have a link in all meta sites to Meta?

Comment: I found a duplicate question [Can we link meta.SO from meta.x.SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68495/can-we-link-meta-stackoverflow-from-meta-x-sx), but no answer there. As noted in waiwai's answer, there -is- a link that I want, but I find its usability pretty deficient/hidden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sixth link in the list of sites in the footer of full SE sites and their corresponding meta site (but not beta sites) is the MSO link.

Comment: OK...so it's there...but it's not noticeable, so it's not particularly useful.

Comment: It's useful now that you know it's there ;)  All kidding aside, I think it would help to maybe put it in the header too.  Also, keep in mind that the "StackExchange" -> "All Sites" drop down will have a link to it too.

Comment: @jmort253 True about the drop-down. But, depending on how many sites you're on and the rep you have across those sites and MSO, it's quite possible that it's going to be buried quite deeply.