# Searching in any meta site should include results from Meta.SE

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search, meta, per-site-meta

This was an idea in response to my answer on [Meta hasn't changed at all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251375/meta-hasnt-changed-at-all/251426#251426).

As we migrate questions from Meta.SO (or any other meta) to Meta.SE, those questions will be removed from the original site.
So commonly asked questions will get asked again, migrated, closed as duplicate again, and asked again...

Searching before posting would not work, because the question would have been migrated to SE, and not searchable in Meta.SO.
Hence the suggestion: all other meta sites (like Meta.SO) should include **searches** and **"Questions that may already have your answer"** from Meta.SE. (or any other meta sites)

**This could indicate clearly that a question is from Meta.SE**, or not and just have the results merged in. (There are pros and cons for each, from ease of development to interfacing issues.)
Hopefully this would cut down on duplicate questions that are already in Meta.SE from appearing elsewhere.

Comment: I rather prefer the local 'government' of MSO to provide a filter in the form of human beings telling folks about how the guys over at the central federal government have already worked out that specific idea (in a rural drawl), and *translating* that idea to the local community. A lot of the time translation == copying, but I want to find where the ideas will *diverge*. Sending people over to MSE will stifle diversion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Similar sentiments. However this more for existing entranced answered meta questions. New unique questions should not face an issue. However, if there is a very site specific reason to repost it.... let it be duplicated!

Comment: I mean that for those supposedly entrenched Meta posts, we want to give the SO constituency the chance to find their own answers. Yes, that means that in the early MSO days there'll be a bit of a wild-west land grab on those hot-button issues, but that's **fine**!

Comment: I think this makes a ton of sense - I'll bring it up in the team call today. We're in the midst of upgrading elastic to 1.10 before our data center move so it may be delayed a bit until that's complete (library updates, pull requests and such in play) but hopefully we can do something good here.

Comment: @NickCraver Thats good to hear, honestly though its value would not be seen till Meta.SE starts to mature. And that would take some time =P

Comment: I wouldn't expose all of MSE to all per-site metas, a lot of stuff there is simply not relevant. My own suggestion was [to make a set of FAQ posts about site mechanics available on all metas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171655/make-network-wide-faq-posts-available-on-per-site-metas). This would limit it to posts known to be relevant to all sites, and would also avoid sending users to a different meta they might not even know about.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't agree about the duplicate, but now there's a nice proposal on MSO: [Meta.SE content should be discoverable on Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252290/meta-se-content-should-be-discoverable-on-meta-so).

Comment: @NickCraver Did anything ever happen about this idea?  I just spent a lot of time writing up a MSO post (carefully reviewing the suggested duplicates), before realizing it was a better fit on MSE.  As soon as I copied over the title to MSE, a perfect duplicate showed up.

Comment: P.S. This is a valid question about how to effectively use Meta.StackExchange.  It is however marked as a duplicate of a question with a suggested answer that *introduces the concept of Meta.StackExchange as a solution.*  Not terribly useful.  The [MSO question @Arjan posted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252290/meta-se-content-should-be-discoverable-on-meta-so) appears to be the only open, if somewhat abandonned, discussion on this issue.

Answer (score 9):

My first reaction to your request was *Oh dear no for the sake of all that is holy no NO NO NO*.

MSE has a hell of a lot of cruft. Unending rehashing of the same topics all over again. Long-obsolete answers that nobody's bothered to upgrade. Threads about Stack Overflow that are irrelevant to other sites. Shoving this at the face of people who're looking for answers relevant to their site would be a profound disservice.

Even as an experienced, cross-site user, I definitely do not want results from MSE to be mixed into my searches on child metas.

What would make sense would be a modification of your suggestion. Do not merge MSE and child meta results, but **when searching on meta, provide a link to the same search on the main meta**. No mixing of content, but do let the user know that the answer they're looking for may be in another castle.