# Add indication of the existence of Meta.SE on all meta sites

Tags: feature-request, meta, per-site-meta

Prompted by [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266847/512728) of a relatively new SO user that he did not know there was a Meta.SE:

*I suggest putting a notice on all Meta sites.*

A good place would be to extend the bottom text of all meta front pages:

> Looking for more? Browse the complete list of questions, or popular tags. Help us answer unanswered questions.

Change it to e.g.

> Looking for more? Browse the complete list of questions, or popular tags. Note that the generic [Meta StackExchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) contains questions and answers that apply to **all** StackExchange sites.
>   Help us answer unanswered questions.

---

Related suggestion but not similar [When searching on meta, provide a link to the same search on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230122/189029)

Comment: Most users don't need to know about the network Meta. What problem would informing them about it solve?

Comment: I'd say any generic question about the workings of the site(s). As I understood it the intention was to move generic Q&A from the different metas to meta.se.

Comment: Site moderators and Stack Exchange employees can move such questions around - still no need for most users to know anything about the network Meta.

Comment: There is already a link to MSE from each and every page in all sites, both main and meta: under "OTHER" in the footer.

Answer (score 5):

How often do you address your government directly? Not that often I guess. You usually go to your town hall and they tell you in some specific situation you have to go there.

I think that counts for Meta SE too. Often, users will have enough of their own site's meta. They often don't understand the specific situations they need to go 'Capitol Hill'.

The people at the site's meta (town hall) are qualified enough to point users to Meta SE when appropriate. And if you are here long enough, and you are a frequent visitor of your own site's meta, you will come to know about Meta SE soon enough.

Comment: OTOH, I go through the laws and orders issued by the government quite often (to build on your analogy).

Comment: The 'laws' are specified in the help center, and there is no visible indication where the rule comes from (if it is global or not). Thus your analogy doesn't go up entirely.