# Automatic cross-meta "linked" sidebar

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, per-site-meta, linked-questions

Duplication across various meta sites is inevitable and [okay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55778/migrate-questions-from-meta-stackexchange-sites-to-meta-stackoverflow-com/56656#56656):

> A certain amount of duplication between sites is fine — in my estimation about 10 to 15 percent.

Each site is slightly different and will have different customs, but sometimes, content is [duplicated nearly verbatim](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180/what-does-voting-mean-and-why-is-it-important) (I've seen a few more examples) on purpose, with a link back to the original.  This is fine, let each meta site control what they need to emphasize to their users — but please continue to include those links, especially back to *this* meta site as it has much more extensive information and many more eyeballs to keep it updated.

In these cases where a link is added, could the other site automatically include a link back in the "linked" sidebar?

I would think this is a useful feature for the non-meta sites too; though there could be some identity dilution for a fledgling site, and cross-site links are much rarer in the first place, on main sites.  However, it seems especially useful given the large overlap of per site metas.

Comment: It's not the most elaborate of phrased questions, but [this Tobias request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59569/also-display-other-se-site-links-as-linked-questions) is asking for this on the full global scale. Personally, I think the meta version will be more useful, with a stipulation that same-site links would get priority in the listing.

Comment: @Grace: I knew I'd seen it requested for main sites before, thanks for the link.

Comment: I linked to an [faq] as example, but this also applies to (and is perhaps even more useful for) [bug] and [support].

Comment: related: [Allow site-specific metas to indicate duplicates of questions on the main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175991/165773)