# Allow site-specific metas to indicate duplicates of questions on the main meta

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, per-site-meta

One of the users on Academia just posted the question "[Should comments with multiple @ references be allowed](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/482/should-comments-with-multiple-references-be-allowed)", which is a duplicate of the question "[Allow more than one @name notification per comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment)" on this meta. This has happened before, and is perfectly understandable; users may not even know this site exists, so they wouldn't know to check here. We've had this happen before (most recently [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/bad-rendering-on-ipad-mini)).

The problem is, when I try to close a question as "duplicate", I get the following:

[image]

My request is for the software to **allow duplicates from site-specific metas to point to questions on the main meta**.

Comment: What main Meta? MSO? Do you seriously want to point your users to this hellhole? Just answer the question on your Meta... Oh, and I see you closed the question as "off topic", that's... not right. The Academia crowd has their own Meta, and all their Meta questions are on topic there.

Comment: I *thought* this was a duplicate, but I can't find it. Basically, just answer the question on your meta and maybe link here as the source of the information. Not every user on the network is expected to participate/know about Stack Overflow/Meta Stack Overflow (even if it *is* the network-wide meta).

Comment: You guys really seem to view this place as similar to a port-a-potty at a carnival... everyone has to go there, but everyone hates being there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Users of other SE sites should not even have to know Meta.SO exists, the per-site meta should be enough for all their needs. Telling users that they have to go to some other strange site can be a rather bad user experience, especially with a rough place like Meta.SO.

The community team has repeated this principle again and again, every time this issue comes up. So being able to close as a dupe of Meta.SO would work against this principle.

And while there is a lot of duplication between MSO and the per-site metas, often the issues are also subtly different, and closing the local posts in favor of the global ones would not be appropriate.

There should be some better ways to access some MSO information from the per-site metas, but I don't think cross-site closing as duplicates is the right way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by a "rough place"?